# Store an array from a 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 2-d array, we call `arr2[3][3]`. If I want to store the first row of `arr2` to a new array, we call `arr1[3]`, how would I do that?

I tried `int arr1[] = arr2[0]`. But it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a problem statement.  Tell us specifically the behavior you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

In C you would have to copy the row of array2 into the array1 using a for loop like so..

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    arr1[i] =arr2[0][i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either assign each element using a loop

```
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
    arr1[i] = arr2[0][i];
```

Alternatively, you can use memcpy.

```
memcpy(&arr1[0], &arr2[0][0], sizeof(int) * columnSize);
```

Make sure that the array being copied to has enough space when doing this approach, otherwise funky stuff will happen (easier to overlook here than with iteration)